# Autenticação User-App do Twitter

Tags: python, twitter-api

Estou desenvolvendo alguns scripts Python com a intenção de trazer tweets específicos e efetuar análises posteriores, porém estou com dúvidas referentes ao tipo de autenticação do Twitter.

Pelo que notei, existem dois tipos de autenticação, a User-Based Authentication e a User-App Authentication.

Minha dúvida é diretamente referente aos RATE LIMITS que os tipos de autenticação me permitem. No User-Based posso trazer 180 itens a cada Window (15 minutos) e o User-App me possibilita o número de 450 itens.

O que devo fazer para efetuar a User-App Authentication? Pois só encontrei informação referente a User-Based.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o [twython](https://twython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
Um exemplo de uso:

```
from twython import Twython, TwythonError

OAUTH_TOKEN = ''
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = ''
APP_SECRET = ''
APP_KEY = ''

twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)

try:
    twitter.update_status(status='@MrMarcioPessoa isso funciona mesmo')
except TwythonError as e:
    print e
```

Para obter o conteúdo das variáveis APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN e OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, siga o passo a passo do website [Twitter Application Management](https://apps.twitter.com/).